# Location for the key for degrees temperature

Tags: imac

Where's the Degree key on the standard QWERTY English keyboard? I use a iMac using OS 10.14.2. I am looking for the key to describe a temperature such as 98.6 degrees Fahrenheit.

Comment: There isn't one on a standard QWERTY English keyboard..

Answer (score 1):

After I read the response I called a friend whois a programer and was told to try Shift-Option-8 and it works on my mac. I don't know if it works on Windows.